# How to access date row in Pandas' DataReader?

Tags: python, json, pandas, datareader, yahoo-finance

I'm using Python's [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to get some finance data from Yahoo Finance, which is a builtin functionality of pandas_datareader. I wish to access the dates it prints out but it doesn't seem to be in the columns nor in the json I require but is there when I print out the object:

```
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 1)
goog = DataReader('GOOGL', 'yahoo', start)
goog.to_json(None, orient="records") # this doesn't include dates!
print(goog) # this prints out the dates along with the other data!
print(goog.columns) # prints every column except the date column
```

How can I include the dates along with the other data in the json string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas dataframes have an index that is used for grouping and fast lookups. The index is not considered one of the columns. To move the dates from the index to the columns, you can use `reset_index()`, which will make `Date` a column and make the index just a sequence of numbers counting up from 0.

So to export as JSON with the dates included:

```
goog.reset_index().to_json(None, orient='records', date_format='iso')
```

Answer (score 4):

`list(goog.index)` gives you the dates as a list of timestamps.

For getting the dates in the json, I had a quick look at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html). Try this:

```
print goog.to_json(orient="index", date_format='iso')
```

Comment: Is there an elegant way to merge that list with the reset of the data so I can export to JSON more easily?

Comment: reset_index() solves my problem completely but this is certainly a step in the right direction so +1, thanks!